# Angular JS: ng-switch not working

Tags: angularjs-directive, ng-switch

I am trying to use ng-switch in my application.

```
In Routing configuration :

when('/Test/:TestName/formEditor/:openedFrom', {
        templateUrl: 'Testing.html',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
    })
```

In my HTML

```
  <div ng-switch="openedFrom">
    <ul class="breadcrumb" ng-switch-when="fromTab1">
        <li><a href="#/solutions" id="act_
   </ul>
   <ul class="breadcrumb"  ng-switch-when="fromTab2" >
         <li><a href="#/abc">Visitors</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

The way I pass the Openedfrom is

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/Test/{{TestName}}/formEditor/fromTab1">Tab 1</a>

  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/Test/{{TestName}}/formEditor/fromTab2">Tab 2</a>
```

The Breadcrumbs are not rendered at all.
Once i remove ng-switch everything seems to work fine. Can someone suggest ?

Comment: Did you attach your openedFrom to the scope ? like `$scope.openedFrom = $routeParams.openedFrom` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are rendering the div with `ng repeat` and `ng switch`. You can use by `ng-if` .

```
<div>
   <ul class="breadcrumb" ng-if="openedFrom=='fromTab1'">
    <li><a href="#/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="breadcrumb"  ng-if="openedFrom=='fromTab2'" >
      <li><a href="#/abc">Visitors</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```